# Is this question on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, off-topic, specific-question

I am struggling a bit with the nuances of on and off topic questions. Is this [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34302/how-widespread-is-the-safe-environment-program-in-catholic-catechetical-programs) on topic? If so under which acceptable question format does it fall? Don't misunderstand me, I'm not pointing fingers at anyone: I'm just trying to get a better feel for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's basically a (current) history question. Answers would be based on statistics showing how widespread it is, or (as the one answer so far does) show a policy instructing it to be widespread.

Comment: It's on-topic in that it's probably definitively answerable as curiousdannii points out.

Comment: The plot thickens. I really thought I got it then. :(

Comment: OK so would this question be on topic if it instead asked "What is the use of redoing the safe environment program in Catholic Catechetical programs annually?"

Comment: No, but it would be if it asked why the Catholic department in charge of it thinks it is worthwhile redoing.

Comment: Yes I could guess that one. One thing that seems very well established is that denominational reference frames focus questions. However, you can't always apply them.